# Allow location access for any websites in Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I just want to scrap some websites using Selenium. Most Ecommerce websites and food websites only give you the data after you give them your location access. I just want to automate the location access using Selenium. Here is my code

```
def geoLocationTest():
    options = Options() 
    options.add_argument("--enable-features=PermissionDefaultSettingForGeolocation:1")


    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)
    Map_coordinates = dict({
        "latitude": 28.697905669937008,
        "longitude": 77.17005421543875,
        "accuracy": 100
        })
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", Map_coordinates)
    driver.get("https://www.zomato.com/")
    time.sleep(10)
    raw_data = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//html")
    print(raw_data.text)

geoLocationTest()
```

The given code is working for websites like https://www.gps-coordinates.net/my-location But it's not working for websites like https://www.zomato.com/ and https://www.swiggy.com/. Can anyone have any solution so that I can give location access to websites like those mentioned above?
I want to give location access to any website automatically using Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You must now set permissions for the origin/domain to allow `geolocation` before setting the location.

Here's a full script that grants `geolocation` permissions to https://www.openstreetmap.org/, and then sets the location before navigating to that site:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.execute_cdp_cmd(
    "Browser.grantPermissions",
    {
        "origin": "https://www.openstreetmap.org/",
        "permissions": ["geolocation"],
    },
)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd(
    "Emulation.setGeolocationOverride",
    {
        "latitude": 48.87645,
        "longitude": 2.26340,
        "accuracy": 100,
    },
)
driver.get("https://www.openstreetmap.org/")
driver.find_element("css selector", "span.geolocate").click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```